# Fractional Exponents and Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

When dealing with fractional exponents like in the question below, how do  you combine them so the two "n's" in the first fraction become one? ((how do i combine $4/3$  with $1/3$))
The aim is to end up with only one 'n' in that fraction. Same goes for the 'm'.
\begin{align*}
& \frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}mn^{\frac{4}{3}}}{5^{\frac{1}{3}}m^{\frac{1}{6}}n^{\frac{1}{3}}} \div \frac{n}{2m^{\frac{1}{6}}5^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\
& = \frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}mn^{\frac{4}{3}}}{5^{\frac{1}{3}}m^{\frac{1}{6}}n^{\frac{1}{3}}} \cdot \frac{2m^{\frac{1}{6}}5^{\frac{1}{3}}}{n}\\
& = 
\end{align*}

Comment: Exponent rules are the same for integers and fractions.  So $n^{\frac{1}{3}}\times n^{\frac{4}{3}}=n^{\frac{5}{3}}$.  And when dividing, you subtract exponents similarly.

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information about how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see this is what your term looks like:

$\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}m n^{\frac{4}{3}}}{5^{\frac{1}{3}}m^{\frac{1}{6}}n^{\frac{1}{3}}} \cdot \frac{2m^{\frac{1}{6}}5^{\frac{1}{3}}}{n}$

$=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}m n^{\frac{4}{3}}}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}\cdot \frac{2}{n}$

$=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}m n^{\frac{4}{3}}}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}} \cdot \frac{2^{\frac{3}{3}}}{n^{\frac{3}{3}}}$

$=\frac{2^{\frac{4}{3}}m n^{\frac{4}{3}}}{n^{\frac{4}{3}}}$

$=\sqrt[3]{2^4}\cdot m$